# Control 9.6v battery line (on/off) with a 5v I/O pin?

Tags: power, relay, control

I would like to control a DC 9.6v battery line (on/off) with a 5v digital I/O pin on a little microcontroller. I *think* the best way to do it is using a small relay (something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/100)), but I'm not sure so I'm here seeking the counsel of 9000's help.

Comment: How much current do you need to draw.  You could probably get away with a MOSFET or other silicon switch as opposed to a relay.

Comment: Somewhere arround 2-2.5A.

Comment: Digikey finds over 12000 suitable products. Any further criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That relay should work. Here's one way to design this sort of switch.

**Dont forget the diode!**
The diode's purpose here is to make it safe to switch the power off across the inductor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwKZGp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Cody Smith, note: You'll probably want a diode like 1N4001 if you plan on going up to 2.5A. This design wasn't meant to show you the parts numbers you need, just the components